# Qt Creator 5.8 Android Development NDK x64 bit error "No Rule to make target.."

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

So I've been using Qt Creator for quite sometime now, but I wanted to try out their development for Android devices (Usually use Android Studio). Main reason is because I prefer C++.

I created a simple Qt Quick application, and can't even get it to run. I made no changes to the program whatsoever. It recognized my device, and I have Android SDK, NDK, and ANT set up properly (from the Qt official page).
The error I'm getting is a pretty popular one, yet so far I've seen no solutions for it.
The error reads **"mingw32-make:No rule to make target'......\Downloads\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\cxx-stlgnu-ibstdc++\4.9\include\profile\impl\profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h', needed by 'main.obj'.  Stop."**

Debugging is enabled on my device, everything is set up properly, device is being recognized, yet I have NO idea why I'm getting this error.

Any help would be much appreciated. It's infuriating.
[image: Device recognized]

[image: Error]

Comment: Does just a build (without deploying to device) work?

Comment: Also [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.8_Tools_and_Versions) says you need NDK10. I know from experience that 11 also works, at least on my linux box, but I also recall problems with newer versions.

Comment: Build doesn't work. Build gives that error but I will try to download NDK10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED FOR THIS PROBLEM.
When using Qt Creator, no matter what version, on a windows computer the file path is the key to this problem. The length of the path.
Extracting the NDK folder and putting that folder DIRECTLY in the C:\ drive will make this build without any problems.

Leaving it in the downloads folder makes the file path TOO long for Qt Creator, hence it wont build.